# Hashing with the Division Method - Choosing number of slots?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, probability

So, in CLRS, there's this quote

> A prime not too close to an exact power of 2 is often a good choice for m.

Several Questions...

1. I understand how a power of 2 will just be the lower order bits of your key...however, say you have keys from a universe of 1 to 1 million, with each key having an equal probability of being any number from universe (which I'm guessing is a common assumption about your universe if given no other data?) then wouldn't taking say the 4 lower order bits result in (2^4) lower order bit patterns that were pretty much equally likely for the keys from 1 to 1 million? How am I thinking about this incorrectly?
2. Why a prime number? So, if power of 2's aren't a good idea, why is a prime number a better choice as opposed to a composite number close to a power of 2 (Also why should it be close to a power of 2...lol)?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find a hash table that works well for typical input data, and typical input data does things that you wouldn't expect from good random number generators. Very often you get formatted or semi-formatted strings which, when converted to numbers, end up as K, K+A, K+2A, K+3A,.... for some integers K and A. If K+xA and K+yA hash to the same number mod m, then (x-y)A must be 0 mod m. If m is prime, this can only happen if A = 0 mod m or if x = y mod m, so one time in m. But if m=pq and A happens to be divisible by p, then you get a collision every time x-y is divisible by q, which is more often since q < m.

I guess close to a power of 2 because it might be convenient for the memory management system to have blocks of memory of the resulting size - I really don't know. If you really care, and if you have the time, you could try different primes with some representative data and see which of them are best in practice.

Comment: I would venture `A prime not too close to an exact power of 2 is often a good choice for m` is basically another way to say prime with a lot of intermixed ones and zeros. Basically, good bit mixer. Exact power of 2 will have one bit set - not good. Mersenne prime is all ones and then all zeroes - not good. You need really some mix of ones and zeroes